# JMX monitor with FUSE ESB

Tags: jmx, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I'm using FUSE ESB and i wondering, is there any possibilities to connect some JMX monitor ?

I have connectec JMX monitor to normal tomcat, but i think that it is good idea, to have controll over serwer load, where i have FUSE ESB instance.

Do you have any experience with it?

I will be greatefull for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read this QA as well where its discussing monitoring of SMX / FuseESB
[Administration and Monitoring of Apache-Camel routes in ServiceMix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723682/administration-and-monitoring-of-apache-camel-routes-in-servicemix)

But rule of thumb is that SMX / Fuse ESB is running on a JVM and offers JMX management capabilities, and any standard JMX compliant tooling can access these information.

For example with Camel we have an extensive number of JMX mbeans, you can gain details about your Camel applications, such as performance statistics, control lifecycle of Camel routes, consumers, etc. And see thread pool utilization, and so forth.

FuseSource offers documentation about Fuse ESB. For example there is some details about configuring JMX here: http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/esb_runtime/ESBRuntimeJMXConfig.html

Answer (score 1):

yep, you can use JMX (jconsole, visualVM, etc)...its enabled by default (see the /bin/servicemix shell script and /etc/system.properties for config)

see these links for more details (though they are a bit dated)...

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SMX4/Remote+JMX+connection
- http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/users-guide/jmx.html